# Unable to show "Edit" icon of "react-native-vector-icons" on ios

Tags: react-native, react-native-vector-icons

I am working on a React Native application. I am using react native vector icons. I am unable to show edit icon, here is my code

```
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';    

<Icon style={{marginTop : '1.5%'}} name="Edit"/>
```

This shows me question mark instead of icon.

But if i do

```
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';    

<Icon style={{marginTop : '1.5%'}} name="area-chart"/>
```

I get the "area chart" icon. Why "area chart" icon is working and not "edit" icon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think name should be in small case letter like,

```
<Icon style={{marginTop : '1.5%'}} name="edit"/>
```

For more info refer [this](https://fontawesome.com/icons?d=gallery&q=edit) & [this](https://oblador.github.io/react-native-vector-icons/).

Answer (score 1):

Try using the type="font-awesome"
`<Icon style={{marginTop : '1.5%'}} type="font-awesome" color: "pickYourColor" name="edit"/>`